# Запуск отдельного теста в тест-классе используя JUnit Parameterized

Tags: java, junit

Не могу запустить отдельный тест в параметризированном тестовом классе. Если запускать весь класс - всё работает, а вот отдельно - нет. Возможно, всё-таки есть способ это сделать?

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizeTest {
    private int valueA;
    private int valueB;
    private int expected;

    public ParameterizeTest(int valueA, int valueB, int expected) {
        this.valueA = valueA;
        this.valueB = valueB;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}:sumOf({0}+{1})={2}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> dataForTest() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {1, 1, 2},
                {2, 6, 8},
                {18, 2, 20},
                {13, 15, 28},
                {1, 5, 6}
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void paramTest() {
        assertEquals(expected, (valueA + valueB));
    }
}
```

Comment: А каким образом ты запускаешь тест отдельно? Может проблема как раз в том, что твоя запускалка не может понять, как правильно запустить тест.

Comment: В Eclipse и через консоль maven'ом. Результат одинаковый

Results :

Tests in error: 
  Filter.initializationError »  No tests found matching Method testBlaBla...